# Am having problem uploading my image to cloud firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

These are the codes am using to upload the images.

```
private void uploadImage() {
        StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("products/"+id+".png");
        storageReference.putFile(uri)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        storageReference.getDownloadUrl()
                                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                                                .collection("products")
                                                .document(id)
                                                .update("image", uri.toString());
                                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                });
    }
```

I tried using the above codes, and I wanted to insert the image into the image field in my cloud firestore, but it is giving me error.
These are the two major errors am having.

1. E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
   Object does not exist at location.
2. Caused by: java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found."  }}

Comment: The problem isn't with Firestore.  It's with Cloud Storage.  Have you debugged this down to the specific line of code that causes the error?  Which line is that?  Please edit the question to share your debugging details.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Doug asked for, and please also respond using @.

Comment: @Doug Stevenson. Thanks for helping I really appreciate that. The problem has been solved. And it was exactly what you were talking about "Cloud Storage".